# What does moz-do-not-send do?

Tags: html-email

I see the `moz-do-not-send="true"` attribute in the HTML of emails all the time. Whenever I send links in emails with Thunderbird, it adds it to the `<a>` tag. What does the `moz-do-not-send="true"` attribute do?

When I looked it up, I couldn't find a clear answer, but instead suggestions to use it when writing email HTML with no explanation of what it does.

Comment: Giving what's described in [How to send HTML emails with images that load from web pages? Ideally with Thunderbird](https://superuser.com/q/687350/34985) it sounds like omitting that attribute causes Thunderbird to download the remote resource and embed it directly in the email, whereas including that attribute keeps it as a link to be retrieved by the recipient.

Comment: Note that modern mail readers suppress fetching from links by default to protect privacy by foiling "web bugs."  If you want your image to appear in the recipient's mail reader, it generally must be embedded, not linked.

Comment: No image involved in an anchor tag, so no idea what it is there for. TB's editor is so far out of date and no-one wants to work on it. Probably there as an oversight that has no obvious effect if you remove it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since [at least 2004](https://web.archive.org/web/20041010054736/http://ed.mullen.home.comcast.net:80/Mozilla/moz_remote.html), Thunderbird has been designed by default to include the full image file contents of images inserted in composed emails. If `moz-do-not-send` is absent or `false`, then upon sending the email, Thunderbird [downloads the image and attaches it](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=596797#c3) to the email.

**The `moz-do-not-send` attribute is a signal used internally by Thunderbird to tell it not to include the full image file contents, but instead to simply link to the external image.** It's a [proprietary attribute](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=596797#c8) used internally by Mozilla-derived software; it has never been part of any HTML specification.

This is best documented at [MozillaZine here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Creating_complex_mails_with_inline_images#Remote_images). You can see details of the use of this attribute in the [Thunderbird source repository here](https://github.com/mozilla/releases-comm-central/search?q=moz-do-not-send).

Comment: It is not an IMG tag we are talking about, it is an anchor A.

Comment: You can apply the very same concept to an anchor too, see my answer.

Answer (score 9):

Cant add a comment,  due to the 50 reputation restriction..  Just need to alert to the fact that the checked "solution" is a bit off-topic. All the answers here refer to `<img>` tags which is not what the OP asked about. The question refers to anchor tags. ie `<a moz-do-not-send="true" href="https://blah.blah">blah.blah</a>`
So what does `moz-do-not-send` do for an anchor in an email?

Comment: Thanks. I found it being added to an HTML document I was editing with SeaMonkey's Composer (HTML editor) and wondered why this odd tag was showing up.

Comment: It does the very same thing: Not embedding the source. See my answer for details, and ideas on why one might _want_ to embed the source.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on the existing answers and their comments, but posting a new answer in order to include the image:

When composing an email and selecting Insert -> Link, the dialog that pops up gives you the option to "attach the source of this link to the message". So it is exactly the same concept as with an image. This feels a bit weird when the link points to a website, but it makes totally sense when it points to a file.

[image: Screenshot]

Actually, it may only feel weird nowadays where websites are often fancy interactive things with a ton of styling and scripting, but when thinking back in time to when (1) websites were little more than informative plaintext *documents* with a few HTML tags scattered through them and (2) people were not connected to the Internet 24/7 due to cost reasons, one starts to understand why this option was included ages ago.

On another note, with links breaking or their content vanishing so often, the more I think about it, I kind of start to like this option from a reproducibility viewpoint.